# all outlets are correct, this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key listTitle

Tags: swift

I kept getting this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key listTitle error, but all my outlets are correct.

I tried to reconnect all the outlets and make sure nothing goes wrong, but this error is still here.

```
@IBOutlet weak var listTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var itemTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var likeRate: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var counter: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    listTitle.text = addedListTitle

    slider.value = 1
    likeRate.text = "1"
}


@IBAction func addPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    if (itemTextField.text!==""){
        counter.text = "You must enter a name for the item"
    }
    else {

        elementCount += 1
        addedItem[itemTextField.text!] = elementRate

        if elementCount < 2
        {
           counter.text = "You have \(elementCount) element in the list"
        }
        else
        {
            counter.text = "You have \(elementCount) elements in the list"
        }
        itemTextField.text = ""
        slider.value = 1
        likeRate.text = "1"
        elementRate = 1
    }
}
@IBAction func finishPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    if (elementCount == 0){
        counter.text  = "You must enter at least one element"
    }
    else{
        addTitle()
        addItems()

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "addToGenerate", sender: self)
    }
}

@IBAction func cancelPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "addToHome", sender: self)
}

func addTitle() {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let newList = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Lists", into: context)

    newList.setValue(addedListTitle, forKey: "listTitle")

    do
    {
        try context.save()
        print("SAVED")
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}

func addItems() {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let newItemList = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Items", into: context)

    for item in addedItem {
        newItemList.setValue(item.key, forKey: "itemName")
        newItemList.setValue(item.value, forKey: "rate")
        newItemList.setValue(addedListTitle, forKey: "listTitle")
    }

    do
    {
        try context.save()
        print("SAVED")
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

}

> ```
>     2019-05-26 03:05:15.230138-0400 Selector[4391:283284] *** Terminating
>     app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>     '[<NSFetchRequest 0x600001c089a0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class
>     is not key value coding-compliant for the key listTitle.'
> ```

Comment: the full project is in this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FZaZK8KmsuBRJUiMCmcM2E_tmYbj1BWu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Tried right clicking the controller in IB and looking at the connection list. Borked connections have a yellow warning symbol. Other possibility is that your controller doesn’t have a custom class set in IB

Comment: I tried to fix all the connections, the error still doesn't go away

Comment: for me it seems like your entity Items doesn't have the listTitle key. so the exception is not related to outlets

Comment: but I do have a listTitle key in my entity

Comment: But NSFetchRequest doesn’t. This has nothing to do with the view controller or the managed object. Read the error message!

Comment: problem seems here newItemList.setValue(addedListTitle, forKey: "listTitle")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the problem in `loadData` method of `FirstTableViewController` class.
You are trying to get the value from `request` `NSFetchRequest` object. You should get the value from the `NSManagedObject` object `result`.

Change

```
if let listTitle = request.value(forKey: "listTitle") as? String {
```

to

```
if let listTitle = result.value(forKey: "listTitle") as? String {
```

Comment: @AlanChang You've used the name `listTitle` for core data attribute and two IBOutlets. Thats the confusion. Use different names